# Creating mean for every row inside dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, row, mean

I want to create mean for every row but the one of the row don't show up in my code. Here is what the dataframe looks like :

```
    A           
0   230     235     210     235
1   345     375     385     378
2   222     292     260     292
```

And here is my code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[230,345,222],' ':[235,375,292],'   ':[210,385,260],'  ':[235,378,292]})
data = df.iloc[:,0:3]
mean = data.mean(axis=0)
```

and what i got as result

```
A      265.666667
       300.666667
       285.000000
dtype: float64
```

I only got 3 mean result but the results should be 4 means. After that I want to average the results again but that is problem for later. Any ideas?

Comment: `df.iloc[:,0:3]` will only take first three rows.

Comment: @CodeIt first three rows? or three columns?

Comment: @QuangHoang Sorry, my bad. It is first three columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use:

```
df.mean()
```

output:

```
A      265.666667
       300.666667
       285.000000
       301.666667
dtype: float64
```

> After that I want to average the results again

you may use:

```
df.mean().mean()
```

output:

```
288.25
```

Comment: sorry but I need to use iloc for this code, I just want to average the first 3 row